is living for [duration]
Here's the context.

She is living here for three years

I think this means

She has been living here for some years until now


and she will live for another few years

It just means the duration of living here. Maybe she's going to move to another city in the future. Or, she's staying there for a specified time(3years) because of the contract.
But, how about this?

She will live here for three years.


She is going to live here for three years.

Does this mean the state of living will last 3 years from now on?

"She is living here for 3 years" is odd phrasing.  What is the context?  Normally you'd say "She has lived here" or "she will live here", or "She expects to live here for a total of three years", or something else.  Where did you read this odd phrasing?

To express that a person who is now living in a particular place moved there three years ago:

She has been living here for three years.

To express that a person who recently moved to a particular place plans to stay there for three years only:

She will be living here for three years.

To express that a person who moved to a place three years ago  plans to stay for a total of four years:

She will be living here for another year.

To express that a person who moved to a place two years ago must  leave after a total of three years:

This time next year  she will have been living here for three years and must leave.



She is living here for three years.

Note that, despite the first sentence of the question, this is not a context. It is simply the sentence we are being asked to interpret. A context would be other sentences providing further information that might influence our understanding of the main sentence.
So, to the main question. By itself, She is living here for three years means She is living here now, and this situation is expected to last for three years. It says nothing about the past. She may have been here for many years; or she may have arrived this morning.
If we want to refer to a past period, we need to change the tenses. This might be one possibility:

She has been living here for six months, [and we expect her to be here for another three years].


a : How long are you here for?
b : I am here for four weeks and arrived two weeks ago
here, "am here" is present, but it is about the duration that started in the past(two weeks ago), and finishes in the future(two weeks later from now). So, I thought present continuous(is living) could work in the same way.
a : how long are you living here?
b : I'm living here for three years. I moved here 2 years ago. and I will live 1 year more.

I wonder who downvoted this correct answer.

@JihoonYang, That is the whole point of context. Your examples are valid, but they only have your assigned meaning because you have given extra information. Imagine that you and I are chatting. I say, How long are you here for? You say, I am here for four weeks. If the conversation stops there, I will understand that you meant, four weeks starting from the time of our conversation. But as you add other details, you are changing the meaning of what you say.

@JihoonYang "I'm here for four weeks," if those four weeks are not yet complete, is similar to how we often use the present tense for future (e.g. "The train leaves at 8 tomorrow"). But this becomes a less likely choice the farther into the future the event is. For me, even four weeks is long enough that I personally wouldn't be likely to use the present tense.
